# How make circle with multiples holes

Tags: unity, c#

In Unity, how can I programmatically make a shape like:

[image: shape]

The gaps in the shape will all be the same size but their number may vary.

Comment: What do you plan to achieve? What's stopping you from using a texture to "fake" these holes? Do you need collision with the holes?

Comment: The circle will rotate. I cant use texture because i want to generate many rings with differents sizes, differents spaces betweens holes and differents sizes for each holes. No i dont want collision with the holes just with the rings. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

Use a `LineRenderer`, and create points programmatically like this:

```
// Lines in circle (in angles)
float[] angles = new float[] {0, 15, 30, 90, 100,120};

for (int i = 0; i < angles.Length; i += 2) {
    // Note that x*PI/180 converts radias "x" to degrees
    point[i].x = Mathf.Cos( angles[i] *Mathf.PI/180 );
    point[i].y = Mathf.Sin( angles[i+1] *Mathf.PI/180 );
}
```

This is pseudocode, so that you can understand the logic behind it. This example will just create a straight line on the edges of the holes, similar to the grey lines in the picture below (note the angles I put are just example and do not resemble the image).

[image]

Now the only question remaining is, how high quality you'd like this to be. From my previous example, from angle[0] to angle[1], you can create as many points as you want, the more points you add, the better quality the circle, at the cost of resources. Of course, for each point you add, you have to interpolate its angle from angle[0] to angle[1].

```
// Lines in circle (in angles)
float[] angles = new float[] {0, 15, 30, 90, 100,120};

for (int i = 0; i < angles.Length; i += 2) {

    for (int j = 0; j < quality; j++) {
        point[i*quality+j].x = Mathf.Cos( 
            Mathf.Lerp(angles[i*quality+j], 
                angles[i*quality+j+1], j/quality) *Mathf.PI/180 );
        point[i*quality+j].y = Mathf.Sin( 
            Mathf.Lerp(angles[i*quality+j], 
                angles[i*quality+j+1], j/quality) *Mathf.PI/180 );
    }
}
```

This is the same example, but it will create `quality` amount of points between to edges, and make the circle smoother. I repeat this is pseudocode and kinda assumes the points are already initialized, it's purpose is to understand the logic of it.

However you mentioned you are not interested in collisions and you just want circles with different sizes and colors. In this case, I could suggest making a texture with a white circle (with holes). Then apply the texture to a `Sprite` and through its `Material` you can change it's color. Since the original color was white, you can change it to any color you want (assuming the background is transparent). You can also scale the `Sprite` to any size you want, depending on your texture quality.

It also sounds like they are going to be used as particles, in this case I could suggest using billboarding (with textures).